# How to initialize at runtime a list with all the static classes of an artifact to be able to dynamically call their methods with their parameters?

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, static-classes, dispatch-table

I have the following problem: I need to test a list of algorithms (~300) with maximum speed performance.

Since every one is unique, I create them as static classes and made a execute() function like bellow.

Each one does have some fixed parameters (the same amount) that eventually, I can make as consts;

I was able to get a list of execute() methods, make a delegate and run it.

Now in C I would make some function pointers and that's it.

Make a array of function pointers.

How can I get a delegate to entire static object, not only to particular method?

Actually I need a list or array of them.

I would prefer to do some heavy lifting in initialization() like reflection, so I can have max. performance at runtime at execute();

Now I am not sure this is the best approach, I'm not expert in C#.

Thanks for suggestions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
  public static class algorithms
  {
    public static void initialize()
    {

      List<Type> types = typeof(algorithms).GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).ToList();

      foreach ( Type t in types )
      {
        var method = t.GetMethod("Execute");

        var execute = (Func<int, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int>), null, method);

        int reply = execute(0x12345678); // I was able to obtain *ptr to execute() for each one

        // how can I obtain a *ptr to entire object in order to access it's members too ?
      }
    }

    // list of ~300 algorithms, unique (so no need to have instances)

    public static class alg1
    {
      public static string Name;      // each share the same parameters
      public static string Alias;

      public static int Execute(int data)     // the same execute function
      {
        // but different processing for each algorithm
        return 1;
      }
    }

    public static class alg2
    {
      public static string Name;
      public static string Alias;

      public static int Execute(int data)
      {
        return 2;
      }
    }

    public static class alg3
    {
      public static string Name;
      public static string Alias;

      public static int Execute(int data)
      {
        return 3;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Now in C I would make some function pointers and that's it. Make a array of function pointers.

In C#  `List<Func<int,int>>` is what you want.

> How can I get a delegate to entire static object, not only to particular method? Actually I need a list or array of them.

That would be `List<Type>`.  A static class never has an "object" only a Type.

Alternatively a more natrural way to model this in C# is to make each algorithm a non-static type, then you can have them all inherit a base class or interface, eg:

```
public abstract class Algorithm
{
    public static string Name;      // each share the same parameters
    public static string Alias;
    public abstract int Execute(int data);
}
public class alg1 : Algorithm
{
    public override int Execute(int data)     // the same execute function
    {
        // but different processing for each algorithm
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then you use `List<Algorithm>` and can write stuff like

```
foreach (var a in algorithms)
{
   var result = a.Execute(3);
}
```